# Python doctest example failure

Tags: python, doctest

This is probably a silly question.

I am experimenting with python doctest, and I try to run [this](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html#simple-usage-checking-examples-in-a-text-file) example

ending with

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testfile("example.txt")
```

I have put "example.txt" in the same folder as the source file containing the example code, but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test_av_funktioner.py", line 61, in <module>
doctest.testfile("example.txt")
File "C:\Python26\lib\doctest.py", line 1947, in testfile
text, filename = _load_testfile(filename, package, module_relative)
File "C:\Python26\lib\doctest.py", line 219, in _load_testfile
return open(filename).read(), filename
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'example.txt'
```

Can I somehow tell/set where the doctest module is searching for the specified file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doctest searches relative to the calling module's directory by default (but you can override this).

Quoting the docs for [`doctest.testfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html#doctest.testfile):

> Optional argument `module_relative` specifies how the filename should be interpreted:
>
> - If `module_relative` is **True** (the default), then `filename` specifies an OS-independent module-relative path. By default, this path is relative to the calling module’s directory; but if the `package` argument is specified, then it is relative to that package. To ensure OS-independence, `filename` should use `/` characters to separate path segments, and may not be an absolute path (i.e., it may not begin with `/`).
> - If `module_relative` is **False**, then `filename` specifies an OS-specific path. The path may be absolute or relative; relative paths are resolved with respect to the current working directory.